# How to display the my menus in the header section that is to the top of the home page?

Tags: category, layout, ce-1.9.1.0, header

I want to display the **my categories** in the **header section** that is to the top of the home page.I already try the code in `page.xml` like this.But it doesn't work .
Please help.

```
<block type="core/text_list" name="content" as="content" translate="label">
    <block type="core/text_list" name="top.menu" as="topMenu" translate="label">
        <label>Navigation Bar</label>
        <block type="page/html_topmenu" name="catalog.topnav" template="page/html/topmenu.phtml"/>
    </block>               
<label>Main Content Area</label>
</block>
```

Answer (score 1):

Create local.xml or your custom.xml file , Use below code to display custom block on "topMenu"

```
<default>
    <reference name="header">
       <block type="core/text_list" name="top.menu" as="topMenu" translate="label">
           <block type="page/html_topmenu" name="catalog.mycustom" template="page/html/custommenu.phtml"/>
      </block> 
   </reference>
</default>
```